# How does Skill Cooldown Reduction work?

Tags: diablo-iii

I found a [Flow of Eternity](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/the-flow-of-eternity) on my monk. How low can I get the cooldown of one skill, in this case Seven Sided Strike?

If there is a cap on skill CDR how does that relate to general skill cooldown?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have done some research and I found that there is no CDR cap. However it is impossible to reach 100% CDR since CDR is calculated with a formula like this (I am bad at theoretical math and creating formulas so I'll just show an example):

Your CDR Stats:

- 50 % Weapon
- 20 % Helmet
- 13 % Boots
- 11 % Chest
- 6 % Belt

This would add up to 100% Right? Yeah it would **add** up but CDR Is **multiplicative** and this is how it's calculated.

> 1 - ((1 - 0.5) * (1 - 0.2) * (1 - 0.13) * (1 - 0.11) * (1 - 0.06))

which basically is:

> 1 - (0.5 * 0.8 * 0.87 * 0.89 * 0.94) = 0.7088632

This means your final CDR is 70.9% which is still quite a lot but as you can see it's absolutely impossible to reach 100% with the current items. But since the final CDR value is rounded, it would be technically possible with items that get you to 99.95% CDR.